# Example: How to find inverse Laplace Transform by integral of the function (5.2-29)

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification, partial-fractions

This is just a demonstration on how to solve the following type of problem.

Find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{54}{s^3(s-3)}\}$ by the given method:

$$\mathcal{L}\{ \int_0^tf(\tau)d\tau\}=\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$$

The textbook answer is $f(t)=2e^{3t}-9t^2-6t-2$.

**My solution**:

$$\frac{54}{s^2(s-3)}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s^2}+\frac{C}{s-3}$$

$$As(s-3)+B(s-3)+Cs^2=54$$

$$As^2-3As+Bs-3B+Cs^2=54$$

$$A+C=0, -3A+B=0, -3B=54$$

$$A=-6, B=-18, C=6$$

$$f(\tau)=-6-18\tau+6e^{3\tau}$$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{s}F(s)\}=\int_0^t(-6-18\tau+6e^{3\tau})d\tau=-6\tau-9\tau^2+2e^{3\tau}\biggr|^{t}_0 $$

$$f(t)=-6t-9t^2+2e^{3t}-2$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for asking but this is just a demo on how to solve this type of problem. Am I doing something wrong or are these kinds of posts okay?

Comment: Post should always ask questions. That said, you can put your original question in a post, and then reply with your own answer. In fact, this is encouraged, and there is a checkbox on the question-posting form that allows you to submit both simultaneously. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer for more.

Comment: For this kind of question you can use "proof verification" tag.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips, good people.

Comment: I do have a question on tags. How do I make a big curly brackets?

Comment: Why don't you use the trick to get rid of $1/s$ *three times* instead of once?